Query Postgres from Duckdb
Does anyone here use duckdb to query PostgreSQL?
ATTACH postgres_attach('hostaddr=192.168.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb connect_timeout=20 user=postgres 
password=masterkey');

always returns like this                      ^

SQL Error: Invalid Error: Failed to prepare COPY "
COPY (SELECT NULL FROM "public"."acessohabilitacao" WHERE ctid BETWEEN '(0,0)'::tid AND '(4294967295,0)'::tid) TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary);
FROM ibroker.main.acessohabilitacao;`
ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "binary"
LINE 2: ...'::tid AND '(4294967295,0)'::tid) TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary);
^
the query

SELECT 
    ['idacessohabilitacao']
FROM 
    ibroker.main.acessohabilitacao
WHERE 
    ctid BETWEEN '(0,0)'::tid AND '(4294967295,0)'::tid) 
TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary);


which version of duck db are you using?
from documentation The old postgres_attach function is deprecated. It is recommended to switch over to the new ATTACH syntax.
https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/postgres.html

Perhaps, should be TO STDOUT WITH(FORMAT binary) or TO STDOUT binary  . See (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

The version is 0.10.3
Nothing change

SQL Error: Invalid Error: Failed to prepare COPY "
COPY (SELECT "idacessosiscomex", "maxforcode", "cdacessosiscomex", "nmusuario", "cpfusuario", "senhadrawback", "paginasiscomex", "tpusuario", "seqinicialidarquivosiscomexweb", "nmloginanvisa", "snativo", "snvisualizarsenha" FROM "public"."acessosiscomex" WHERE ctid BETWEEN '(0,0)'::tid AND '(4294967295,0)'::tid) TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary);
": ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "binary"
LINE 2: ...'::tid AND '(4294967295,0)'::tid) TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary);

I am able to access postgres from DuckDb using the following syntax:
import duckdb
duckdb.sql("""
ATTACH '  
        dbname=postgresdb
        hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
        port=1234
        user=postgresusr
        password=postgresusr@123
    ' AS db (TYPE postgres, READ_ONLY);  

""")

duckdb.sql("""
SELECT * 
FROM db.schema_nm.input_tbl_nm;

""")

